# How to upload files to AWS S3?, I get an error when doing it (using private buckets)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to AWS S3 using getSignedUrlPromise() to obtain the access link since the bucket is completely private, I want it to only be accessible through the links that the server generates with getSignedUrlPromise().

The problem comes when I try to make a Put request to that link obtained since I get the following error, I also leave you the response that I receive.

[image]

Here is the code for configuring aws in nodeJS:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const bucketName = 'atlasfitness-progress';
const region =process.env.AWS_REGION;
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY

const URL_EXPIRATION_TIME = 60; // in seconds

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region,
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
})

export const generatePreSignedPutUrl = async (fileName, fileType) => {

    const params = ({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 60
    })

    const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);

   return url;
}
```

And then I have a express controller to send the link when it's requested:

```js
routerProgress.post('/prepare_s3', verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
  res.send({url: await generatePreSignedPutUrl(req.body.fileName, req.body.fileType)});
})

export { routerProgress };
```

But the problem comes in the frontend, here is the function that first asks for the link and then it tryies to upload the file to S3.

```js
const upload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await JWT.checkJWT();

    const requestObject = {
        fileName: frontPhoto.name,
        fileType: frontPhoto.type,
        token: JWT.getToken()
    };

    const url = (await axiosReq.post(`${serverPath}/prepare_s3`, requestObject)).data.url;
    //Following function is the one that doesn't work
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      body: frontPhoto
  });
    console.log(response);
}
```

And with this all is done, I can say that I am a newbie to AWS so it is quite possible that I have caused a rather serious error without realizing it, but I have been blocked here for some many days and I'm starting to get desperate. So if anyone detects the error or knows how I can make it work I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I note about your code is that you `await` on async operations but do not provide for exceptions. This is very bad practice as it hides possible failures. The rule of thumb is: whenever you need to `await` for a result, wrap your call in a try/catch block.

In your server-side code above, you have two awaits which can fail, and if they do, any error they generate is lost.

A better strategy would be:

```
export const generatePreSignedPutUrl = async (fileName, fileType) => {

    const params = ({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 60
    })

    let url;
    try {
      url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);
    } catch (err) {
      // do something with the error here
      // and abort the operation.
      return;
    }
      

   return url;
}
```

And in your POST route:

```
routerProgress.post('/prepare_s3', verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
  let url; 
  try {
    url = await generatePreSignedPutUrl(req.body.fileName, req.body.fileType);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ ok: false, error: `failed to get url: ${err}` });
    return;
  }
  res.send({ url });
})
```

And in your client-side code, follow the same strategy. At the very least, this will give you a far better idea of where your code is failing.

Two things to keep in mind:

1. Functions declared using the `async` keyword do not return the value of the expected result; they return a Promise of the expected result, and like all Promises, can be chained to both `.catch()` and `.then()` clauses.
2. When calling async functions from within another async function, you **must** do something with any exceptions you encounter because, due to their nature, Promises do not share any surrounding runtime context which would allow you to capture any exceptions at a higher level.

So you can use either Promise "thenable" chaining or try/catch blocks within async functions to trap errors, but if you choose not to do either, you run the risk of losing any errors generated within your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to create a pre-signed URL that can be used to PUT an MP4 file.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2010-12-01',
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION || 'us-east-1',
});

const params = {
  Bucket: 'mybucket',
  Key: 'videos/sample.mp4',
  Expires: 1000,
  ContentType: 'video/mp4',
};

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
console.log(url);
```

The resulting URL will look something like this:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/sample.mp4?
    Content-Type=video%2Fmp4&
    X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
    X-Amz-Credential=AKIASAMPLESAMPLE%2F20200303%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&
    X-Amz-Date=20211011T090807Z&
    X-Amz-Expires=1000&
    X-Amz-Signature=long-sig-here&
    X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

You can test this URL by uploading sample.mp4 with curl as follows:

```
curl -X PUT -T sample.mp4 -H "Content-Type: video/mp4" "<signed url>"
```

A few notes:

- hopefully you can use this code to work out where your problem lies.
- pre-signed URLs are created locally by the SDK, so there's no need to go async.
- I'd advise creating the pre-signed URL and then testing PUT with curl *before* testing your browser client, to ensure that curl works OK. That way you will know whether to focus your attention on the production of the pre-signed URL or on the use of the pre-signed URL within your client.

If your attempt to upload via curl fails with Access Denied then check that:

- the pre-signed URL has not expired (they have time limits)
- the AWS credentials you used to sign the URL allow PutObject to that S3 bucket
- the S3 bucket policy does not explicitly deny your request

Comment: When using curling in my code I get access denied in xml format

Comment: So, I think you're saying that you used the code I posted to create a pre-signed URL, then you used the command line tool curl to attempt to upload a file, as shown, but the response from S3 was an XML payload including `<Code>AccessDenied</Code>`. The most obvious reason is that the credentials you used to sign the request do not have PutObject permission on the indicated bucket. If you use the awscli (`aws s3 cp`) with these credentials can you upload to that bucket?

Comment: Yes I've used your code and I get that Access Denied. Excuse me for my ignorance but what do you refer about using aws s3 cp credentials?

Comment: There is an AWS command line tool called the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It allows you to make AWS API calls from the command line. You can use it to validate your assumptions about, among other things, the permissions associated with a given set of AWS credentials. In your case, the most likely issue is that the permissions associated with your AWS credentials do not allow you to upload to that S3 bucket. If you understand AWS IAM then you should be able to debug this easily. If you don't know IAM, then you should ask whoever provided you with your credentials.

Comment: I don't know how to use it, but now I've realised that in my bucket configuration I have Block all public access, should I have to disable it, (although we must bear in mind that only I should have access to upload and download S3 files)?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions associated with your IAM credentials? Please do that. No, BPA (Block Public Access) will not prevent the use of pre-signed URLs - they're signed URLs, they're not anonymous (public access). Also, installing and using the awscli is simple. It will help you longer term.

Comment: I've realised that I haven't had any acces key, but now I've created one and I've used it when creating S3 object, but the error still there. Now I'm a little confused, should I have to use the access key or the bucket access key? And is this the IAM credentials you are refering to? (Please if you know any video that they explain how to to that let me know)

Comment: I'd recommend some basic IAM tutorials, for example [here](https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/1455-amazon-s3-creating-an-iam-user).